# Extracting information from raw text

Tags: python, regex, spacy, regex-group

**Problem Description**

Here is the text pattern I have:

```
05.04.0090
1


erhältlichen Tableau Interfaces
lassen sich zusätzliche GLT-Kontakte
aufschalten. Das System kann

die zwei Szenarien-Modi "Urlaub" und
Abwesenheit" verwalten. Für beide
Modi können bestimmte Parameter
programmiert werden.

Das WAREMA climatronic Bediengerät
kann preisgleich auch

in den Farben "schwarz" oder
"schwarz/silber" geliefert werden.
Liefern und montieren. 882,75 882,75
```

The above text block has `item_code` that has this norm to write `05.04.0090`
then underneath  is count of the item `1` then  followed by `description of product` then`unit price` in this case EU `882,75`
and at the end total `sum` that is `882,74`

**What i want**
I want to make key value pairs out of it like `dict[{'item_code':'5.04.009','quant':'1','description':'TEXT','unit_price':'882,74','Total_sum':'88,75'}]`

I will be using this pattern in spacy at the end to recognize the entities. Any suggestion regarding  spacy would be great also

**What I have tried?**

```py
pat= re.search(r'\d(.*?)\d',text,re.M)
print(pat.group())
```

Help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: could you provide a minimal working example? That way we could just copy your code, and continue debugging.

Comment: your are asking for spacy ?  For regex working code is given?

Comment: 'unit_price':'882,74','Total_sum':'88,75' are these typos? I can see only 882,75 twice in the text.

Comment: Sorry. its the same number 882.74 once its per/unit price and second time it is total_sum as given in text above.

Comment: This is the best regex I could find so far:
res = re.findall(r'[\d]+(?:\d+)*[\.]*[\,]?\d*(?:\d+)?', text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pprint.pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) function is used for output. For an explanation of the regular expression used, please go to [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/0e7T4P/1).

```
import re
import pprint

data = '''
05.04.0090
1


erhältlichen Tableau Interfaces
lassen sich zusätzliche GLT-Kontakte
aufschalten. Das System kann

die zwei Szenarien-Modi "Urlaub" und
Abwesenheit" verwalten. Für beide
Modi können bestimmte Parameter
programmiert werden.

Das WAREMA climatronic Bediengerät
kann preisgleich auch

in den Farben "schwarz" oder
"schwarz/silber" geliefert werden.
Liefern und montieren. 882,75 882,75


05.04.0091
100
foo bar. 170,42 17042
'''

rx = r'''(?mx)
^
(?P<item_code>\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4})
\s+
(?P<quantity>\d+)
\s+
(?P<description>\S[\s\S]*?)
[ ]+
(?P<unit_price>\d+(?:,\d\d)?)
[ ]+
(?P<total_sum>\d+(?:,\d\d)?)
$
'''
result = [m.groupdict() for m in re.finditer(rx, data)]
pprint.pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'description': 'erhältlichen Tableau Interfaces\n'
                 'lassen sich zusätzliche GLT-Kontakte\n'
                 'aufschalten. Das System kann\n'
                 '\n'
                 'die zwei Szenarien-Modi "Urlaub" und\n'
                 'Abwesenheit" verwalten. Für beide\n'
                 'Modi können bestimmte Parameter\n'
                 'programmiert werden.\n'
                 '\n'
                 'Das WAREMA climatronic Bediengerät\n'
                 'kann preisgleich auch\n'
                 '\n'
                 'in den Farben "schwarz" oder\n'
                 '"schwarz/silber" geliefert werden.\n'
                 'Liefern und montieren.',
  'item_code': '05.04.0090',
  'quantity': '1',
  'total_sum': '882,75',
  'unit_price': '882,75'},
 {'description': 'foo bar.',
  'item_code': '05.04.0091',
  'quantity': '100',
  'total_sum': '17042',
  'unit_price': '170,42'}]
```